# make ggplot2:: stat_bin2d show density instead of counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to make it show within-group densities instead of counts?

```
library(ggplot2);data(diamonds)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, depth)) +  
  stat_bin2d(bins=40)+ facet_wrap(~color)
```

This would make it easier to compare patterns among the groups, as some groups may naturally be more occurring.

The question is slightly similar to: [How to scale (normalise) values of ggplot2 stat_bin2d within each column (by X axis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803999/how-to-scale-normalise-values-of-ggplot2-stat-bin2d-within-each-column-by-x-a) which is also lacking an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, depth)) +  
  stat_bin2d(bins=40, aes(fill = ..density..))+ facet_wrap(~color)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Or would you be happy with a kernel density estimate?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, depth)) +  
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE, n = 25) + 
  facet_wrap(~color) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "light blue", high = "dark red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Or with default grid:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, depth)) +  
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~color) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "light blue", high = "dark red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: can you comment on why you get such different density scales between stat_bin2d and stat_density2d? It looks as if _bin2d is accurate but density2d is too high, assuming everything should sum to 1.