# Density scale difference between stat_bin2d() and stat_density2d(), in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I'm using R. Why do the densities between these two functions differ? I looked at the help files but ddin't see much to indicate what the reason is. I thought my log stretch might be causing the change given that my stat_bin2d density scale is very similar to stat_density_2d before the axis stretch. However I see the same effect in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852209/make-ggplot2-stat-bin2d-show-density-instead-of-counts) and they have linear x/y axes scales.

This was my code:

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))

# log10 scale x and y axes
gg <- gg + scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,1500), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_x_log10(limits=c(0.009,100), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))

# using stat_density2d
gg <- gg + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom="tile", contour=FALSE, n=40)

# using stat_bin2d
gg <- gg + stat_bin2d(bins = 40, aes(fill = ..density..), drop = FALSE)
```

**stat_bin2d()**

[image]

**No log transformation of x and y scales (and drop=TRUE)**
[image]

**stat_density2d()**

[image]

Comment: still no answer..